# Setting Up References Between AutoCAD Files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I've followed the advice listed in the article https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/setting-up-references-between-files to publish a Revit 2018 model and its linked references to Forge.  This works and I can successfully view the entire model with the Forge Viewer.

I haven't been able to get the same procedure to work on AutoCAD drawings with xrefs and am looking for help with this.

Are AutoCAD xrefs supported?

Comment: Hi @JGeerVM, I think it should work. I am building a simple test to verify. Could you also provide the test DWG files ? I can make simple files, but in case yours are specific. In addition, just fyi, post reference for the objects in bucket (by 2 legged token) is also available now https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I'm aware of the post reference api, but have not been successful with this approach. The version/refs api is the only one I have been able to get to work for Revit 2018 projects.  Our application uses 3 legged tokens and the objects are in buckets associated with BIM 360.  I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: the post reference api I mentioned is for the scenario of 2 legged. The http request body format is different to wha with version/refs (for 3 legged). I just wanted to mention this in case you also need it.  It looks you have found the root problem at your side. I will also give a test according to your description

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what kind of response you got when you built the relationship of the two DWGs? 204 or others?

I prepared a DWG and Xref-ed with another DWG. Then I put them to my A360 storage. By Postman scripts, I accessed the two DWGs, and build the relationship with 
[POST projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/relationships/refs](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-POST/) , according to [the blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/setting-up-references-between-files) you also referred to. Finally post the translation job.

With the translated data, I verified the drawing is loaded correctly with the xref drawing.

The DWGs are available at: 
main.dwg  http://a360.co/2AJ9Qga
xref1.dwg: http://a360.co/2mhZ383

The Postman script to build relationship is: (I converted to curl for convenience)
http://a360.co/2CHZGhC

The test harness of loading drawing is: jsfiddle.net/xiaodongliang/y41scm31/

Could you check anything that could help you to figure out the issue at your side?  If you still have the problem, could you provide a test case? If it contains private info, please send it to forge.help@autodesk.com

[image]

[image]

Comment: After some testing, I've found that the problem appears to be with the Xref path.  During publish to BIM 360, I am trying to group my xrefs in a subfolder named 'Reference', but if the Xref is attached from a relative path named '.\Xref\Floor Plan.dwg' the translation engine doesn't appear to find the file.  This behavior is different from Revit, which works even if the relative path is different.

Comment: path would affect.. I will give a test to verify if it is a problem of Forge API or as designed.

Comment: did you determine if this was a problem with the Forge API

Answer (score 1):

Apologize for my late response! I was on an urgent commitment these days.  I can reproduce this issue you found. assume the source files relationship is:

```
main.dwg
\Xref\myxref.dwg
```

On Autodesk 360 Fusion team, the hierarchy is:

```
main.dwg
\ForgeTest\myxref.dwg
```

It succeeded with setting up reference, but the translation (to SVF) reports myxref.dwg is missing.

It can work with the two scenarios:

Either myxref.dwg locates in the same folder of main.dwg, i.e.

```
main.dwg
myxref.dwg
```

even though the source relationship indicates the xref is in a subfolder named 'Xref'.

Or, myxref.dwg locates in a sub folder with the same name,  i.e.

```
 main.dwg
 \Xref\myxref.dwg
```

I logged a change request DERI-4747 with our engineer team .

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  We'll look forward to a resolution for DERI-4747. Hopefully these differences between AutoCAD and Revit can make it to the documentation for the API as known issues.  That way when developers are planning to implement a feature, they can better understand the feasibility of the solution.

Comment: yes, and thank you for reporting this issue that could help us to enhance the related functionalities.